# Тотальный mod_rewrite. Передача всей строки запроса в GET переменную

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Пытаюсь передать все что после `/` в переменную `GET` на `php`, включая дополнительные параметры запроса.
Удалось передать лишь

```
/rand/rand2/?p=1
```

в запросе вида 
http://test.ru/rand/rand2/?rand3=1&rand4=2

Используя код:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ engine.php?u=$1?%1 [L,QSA]
```

Но `&rand4=2` не передается.

Как передать абсолютно все что есть после `http://test.ru/` ?

Решение должно быть универсальным, то есть все что после `/` - полностью случайные данные.

Comment: Не занимайтесь изобретением велосипеда, а загляните в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо большое, как то я забыл что средствами php можно же :))